# Xcode 6.3 - simulator size

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9, simulator

After upgrading Xcode, the x-code simulator appears in a large size. It was working fine before I upgrade it.

Comment: You mean the iOS simulator and it's screen size / zoom ? You can adjust those in the menu bar.

Comment: For example, I selected iPhone5 as device and the soon I run the code, I can see the large size of simulator, which wasn't appearing in such a big size before upgrading

Comment: And if you set the zoom to smaller (in the simulator)?

Comment: How to set a zoom size? There is no particular size I can set with zoom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set your simulator window size easily. Open you simulator. Then go to `Window > Scale` and set it to whatever size that's best for you.

[image: Scaling simulator]

Comment: Without scaling is there is any other way to get appropriate size of the simulator? with 100% scale?

Comment: @ManishaParmar get a larger resolution monitor? just kidding. Not that I know of. Resizing the scale is the only way to do this. By the way, you can easily change the scale with `command + 1`, `command + 2`, etc.

Comment: If you have a retina screen (MacBook Pro/5k iMac), launching the simulator on that will make use of the retina resolution so the simulator will appear smaller. If you then drag it to a regular resolution screen, it'll keep the smaller device size, effectively scaling down by 50%.